# <p>+++ TEXT +++</p> in CMS

Tags: php, html, content-management-system

I'm having a bit of a weird problem. The CMS of our website was developed about 4 years ago, but the person who made it is no longer working for our company so I'm left with the management of it. So far, so good since the CMS works just fine for normal content managing. However we also happen to have a small webshop on our site and the prices and some text needs to be changed. I found the prices were listed in a MySQL table and was able to change them. However, the only text on the page is:

```
<h2>Zand / Grind bestellen</h2>
<p>+++grondstof:bestellen_deel1+++</p>
```

But the page you see as a visitor clearly lists a few options and some text. I know it's difficult for anyone without access to say what's going on, but maybe the +++ indicate it's pointing to something? I have a feeling some PHP is involved since the person made pretty much everything with it.

Despite it being far fetched I hope someone can give me some ideas on what's happening here.

Comment: It looks like it's pointing to some completely custom templating method, but as its' almost certainly code that's only available in your custom CMS, and nobody else knows what it is or does, it's as close to impossible for anyone else to help as it can be

Comment: I was afraid for something like that indeed. I'll see if we can somehow contact the person to see if he's willing to help. Thank you very much for confirming my suspicion though

Comment: have u search the code for the string ?

Comment: So far I can't even locate the code...

Comment: @niek_k - If you can get him to help, make sure that he shows somebody else how the system works, and get him to document as much as possible so that anybody else working on the system for you will have an easier job

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for the suggestions! I will most certainly do that and hope for the best. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I found the code that checks this on the FTP server, as it turns out it's currently not possible to manage this through the CMS.

Thanks to everyone for thinking along!